# How to convert null string to empty string in retrofit2?

Tags: retrofit2

Before moving to retrofit2, I was using volley. To set my pojo value, I was using optString and optInt to retrieve value from JSONObject response. This will replace my null string to empty string and I don't need to add null checks for the same. How will do the same with retrofit2.

Example Json:

```
{
company_name : null
}
```

Pojo class

```
public class company implements Serializable{
@SerializedName("company_name")
private String companyName;

public String getCompanyName(){
return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName){
this.companyName = companyName;
}
```

**String companyName = getCompany();
cause NullPointerException.**

Is there any way to convert every null string to empty string like optString.?

Answer (score 1):

Make `String` type adapter similar

```
public class StringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
     public String read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
       if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
         reader.nextNull();
         //here is the point of interest
         //instead of return null;
         return "";
       }
       return reader.nextString();

     }
     public void write(JsonWriter writer, String value) throws IOException {
       if (value == null) {
         writer.nullValue();
         return;
       }
       writer.value(value);
     }
   }
```

for more details read [this](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

about like this; the ternary operator used is the same as `if`:

```
public void setCompanyName(String value){
  this.companyName = (value==null ? "" : value);
}
```

or try the [Jackson Converter](http://github.com/square/retrofit/wiki/Converters) alike `JsonParserUtil.toPojo(...)` annotated with `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` then there shouldn't be any NULL values passed on - while the setter still would crash on NULL values, unless properly sanitized.

Comment: Yes, this is one possible solution but I have lot of POJOs and doing this in every POJO for every field is time consuming task. I am looking for easier way to do the same.